# Raspberry pi b+ remote access or network access?, Is it possible?

Tags: connection, debian, raspberry-pi

I am a new user for the Raspberry pi B+, I have set it up and I can use it now.
However I bought it because I want to learn how to program then I want to star using it but I want to use the command line. I would like to know if there is a way to connect my laptop to the raspberry via ether net cable or usb then I do not need an external monitor, keyboard and mouse.
Do you know if is this possible?, is there a software for it?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. You only need bootable OS on microSD card with enabled ssh and could use wired network (or wireless network with wifi usb adapter). It is also possible to use com port for console access (most likely you will need usb to com adapter). When I bought my first RPi I was using usb serial cable because I only had microSD with NOOB which require GUI for installation. It took me a long time but now I'm using GUI over wifi (I'm running x2go server on Pi) and I never connected monitor or keyboard to Pi. It will be much easier if you have installed Raspbian with enabled ssh on microSD card.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. It works now!!!. I install a software which name  is Putty, (I am using W7, 64 Bit) so just in case it could help you if you ever needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to to connect your laptop to the raspberry via ether net cable or usb then I do not need an external monitor, keyboard and mouse.

There is a software called putty which can be used to access the terminal of pi.

and there is also a software called VNCviewer which can be used to load the desktop of raspberry pi directly to your laptop....

u just need to set the pi's ip address in file called "cmdline.txt" which u can see in the root folder and u can access the pi through that ip....in putty software which is on your laptop.....

if u want detailed description of this tutorial...u can refer this link also...
https://kushrami.wordpress.com/2015/01/26/how-to-load-raspberry-pis-desktop-on-your-laptop-screen/